# How can i measure the time between HTTP REQUEST & HTTP RESPONSE on server side?

Tags: http, server, httpresponse

So, i have this mobile game and a server. 
I want to measure the processing time of the server like this:
Time (HTTP Response sent) - Time(HTTP request received).

Does anyone can help me ?
Is there any tools to do that ?

Comment: Which server side technology are you using? Java? C++? or something else? Also, do you use web server such as Nginx?

Comment: As far as i know, it was CentOS and a lot of .php files which i don't want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Nginx is used to host PHP, you can use `$request_time` to record the time between request-received and response-sent:

> **$request_time** – Full request time, starting when NGINX reads the first byte from the client and ending when NGINX sends the last byte of the response body

Please refer to the [official document](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-logging-for-application-performance-monitoring/) for more information.

---

If Apache is used to host PHP, you can use `%D` in log ([mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html)).

> **%D** - The time taken to serve the request, in microseconds.

Please refer to this [article](http://www.moeding.net/archives/33-Logging-Apache-response-times.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to view the server response time you can use the chrome dev console and view the time taken for the request-response cycle
[image]

if you want to programmatically calculate (assuming you are using a Node backend) the time use :

```
//receive request
console.time();

// my server code...

console.timeEnd();
//send response
```

Alternatively, you could use the js Date Object

```
const timerStart = new Date();
// my server code...
const timerEnd = new Date();
//timerEnd - timerStart (get time in ms)
//send response to client
```